# Доступ к NFC через Andoid WebView

Tags: android, android-webview, nfc

Пытаюсь реализовать работу web приложения на webview Android.
Возникла проблема при попытке сканировать NFC метки через телефон из этого самого web-приложения.
Выкидывает ошибку с текстом: "Error, scan failed to start. NotAllowedError: NFC permission request denied." внутри WebView. Уверен, что приложение имеет необходимые разрешения.

В манифесте запрос необходимых разрешений прописал:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.NFC" />
```

Тестировал на данной странице, из браузера работает
https://nu-book.github.io/test-form-generator/mod-nfc.html

Подскажите пожалуйста, как можно передать доступ к NFC для WebView, если это возможно.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Возможно это связано с необходимостью разрешения в самом браузере. Попробуйте добавить след код.

```
      webview.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient() {  
             @Override
              public void onPermissionRequest(final PermissionRequest request) {
                     if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
                              request.grant(request.getResources());
                      }
               }
         });
```

Судя по [документации](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NDEFReader/scan) данный метод `NDEFReader.scan` не поддерживается в WebView Android.

Возможно, не в тему, но как вариант можно рассмотреть следующий вариант. В нашем приложении мы использовали [JavascriptInterface](https://android-tools.ru/coding/vzaimodejstvie-webview-s-javascript/) для обмена данными между WebView и нативов. И через JavascriptInterface Web страница запускала чтение данных через NFC и получала данные через обратный вызов JS методов.

Comment: Судя по всему PermissionRequest поддерживает только эти типы разрешений: RESOURCE_VIDEO_CAPTURE, RESOURCE_AUDIO_CAPTURE, RESOURCE_PROTECTED_MEDIA_ID, RESOURCE_MIDI_SYSEX. Разрешений на NFC внутри класса я не нашел.